# Solve the functional equation $f(x)f(1/x)=f(x+1/x)+1$, $f(1)=2$, where $f(x)$ is a polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

Solve the functional equation
$$f(x)f(1/x)=f(x+1/x)+1,\ f(1)=2,$$
where $f(x)$ is a polynomial.

It is easy to check that $f(x)=x+1$ is a solution. Are there any other solutions? My attempt is described as follows.

Since $f(x)$ is a polynomial, we can write it as $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$, where $a_n\neq 0$. Substituting it into the functional equation, we have
$$
f(x)f(1/x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\sum_{j=0}^n a_jx^{-j}=\sum_{\ell=-n}^n \Bigg(\sum_{i=\max(0,\ell)}^{\min(n,n+\ell)} a_ia_{i-\ell}\Bigg) x^\ell $$
and
\begin{align}
f(x+1/x)+1&=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i(x+1/x)^i+1=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\sum_{j=0}^i\binom{i}{j} x^{2j-i}+1\\
&=\sum_{\ell=-n}^n \Bigg(\sum_{\max(\ell,0)\leq j\leq \frac{n+\ell}{2}} a_{2j-\ell}\binom{2j-\ell}{j}\Bigg)x^{\ell}+1.
\end{align}
By comparing the coefficients of $x^\ell$ on both sides of the above two equations and noting that $f(1)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i=2$, we can obtain a very complex system of equations of the coefficients $a_i$, $0\leq i\leq n$. For example, when $n=5$, the system of equations is of the form
\begin{align}
&a_0a_5=a_5,\\
&a_0a_4+a_1a_5=a_4,\\
&a_0a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_5=a_3+5a_5,\\
&a_0a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_5=a_2+4a_4,\\
&a_0a_1+a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_4+a_4a_5=a_1+3a_3+10a_5,\\
&a_0^2+a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2+a_5^2=1+a_0+2a_2+6a_4,\\
&a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=2.
\end{align}
Assuming that $a_5\neq 0$, it is not hard to show that the above system of equations has no solution. But for general case, I have no idea how to solve it or to show it has no solution. I wonder whether there is a clever approach which avoids this tedious computation?

Added. I would like to point out that the condition $f(1)=2$ imposes a strong restriction on the problem. For example, the polynomial $f(x)=1+(1-\sqrt{2})x^2$ satisfies the functional equation but does not satisfy the condition $f(1)=2$. It seems that this condition rules out many solutions.

Comment: As far as I think, the predefined value for $f(1)$ is for us to consider a root of the polynomial rather than defining the polynomial fully, just let $a$ be a root and solve $1+1/x=a$ to get $x=\frac{1}{a-1}$so that $a$ is never $1$ and indeed it's given $1$ is not a zero of the polynomial.

Comment: We have $f(2)=3$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes, we have $f(2)=3$ by setting $x=1$ in the functional equation, but it seems to be hard to get the values of $f(x)$ at other numbers.

Comment: @Shamim I agree with you. The condition $f(1)=2$ seems to suggest us something. Should we solve $x+1/x=a$? as $1+1/x$ does not appear in the functional equation.

Comment: I am so sorry. I misread $x+1/x$ as $1+1/x$

Comment: Taking the derivative we have $f'(1)\cdot2+2\cdot f'(1)(-1)=f'(2)\cdot0$, i.e., $0=0$.

Comment: @XiangYu now the problem seems even harder, both sides are symmetric and thus manipulating will become harder, as I was expecting to do by considering a zero $a$ and defining $g(x)=f(x)+1$ and somehow showing $deg f=1$

Comment: Let $\deg(f)=n$, $a_n\neq0$ and $a_0$ are the leading coefficient and the constant term respectively. Then we get the polynomial identity $$X^nf(X)f(1/X)=X^nf(X+1/X)+X^n$$ comparing leading coefficients of both sides we get $$a_na_0=a_n$$ and hence $a_0=1$. This gives the important information that $0$ is not a root of $f$ with $f(0)=1$ and hence $f(X)\equiv Xh(X)+1$ for some polynomial $h$ with $\deg(h)=n-1$ and $h(1)=1$.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya Actually, by comparing the coefficients of the term following the leading term, we have $a_0a_{n-1}+a_1a_n=a_{n-1}$. Since $a_0=1$ and $a_n\neq 0$, we get $a_1=0$. However, it seems that this technique is not sufficient to determine all the $a_i$.

Comment: We have 
$$f(x) f(1/x) = f(x+1/x) + 1$$ 
$$\sum_0^n a_i x^i \sum_0^n a_i x^{-i} = \sum_0^n a_i(x+1/x)^i + 1 $$ 
Multiply with $x^n$ both sides 
$$\sum_0^n a_i x^i \sum_0^n a_i x^{n-i} = \sum_0^n a_i (x^2+1)^i x^{n-i} + x^n $$
$$(a_nx^n + \cdots + a_0)(a_n + \cdots a_0x^n) = (a_n(x^2+1)^n + \cdots a_0 x^n ) + x^n$$ 
Sub $x=0$ 
$$a_0a_n = a_n \Rightarrow a_0 = 1 $$

Comment: $a_1=0$ does not support the fact that $f(X)=X+1$ is a valid solution if we take $n=1$.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya I implicitly assumed that $n\geq 2$. When $n=1$, the equality should be $a_0 a_{n-1}+a_1a_n=a_{n-1}+1$ because now $2n-1=n$.

Comment: You are right, sorry:)

Comment: Where did you find this problem?  Or did you create it?

Comment: Looking at $\lim_{x\to0^+}$ of both sides informally gives $f(0)=1$ also, as $\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)\over f(x)+1}$ should be $1$.

Comment: Other factoids by looking at complex numbers: $f(x)\ge -1$ for $-2\le x\le 2$; $|f(i)|=\sqrt 2$; $|f(\frac12\pm i\frac{\sqrt 3}2)|=\sqrt3$

Comment: Would it help to look at techniques for solving things like $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)+1$ or $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)+xy$? Your assumption is weaker (but implied by these when $y=1/x$), but maybe applying a technique for similar equations to your situation might yield ideas.

Comment: @BrianTung One of my students asked me this question in the class. I am not clear where it comes from.

Comment: an interesting problem definitely - there are polynomials with non-real coefficients that satisfy the functional equations already in degree $3$ and I think polynomials of any degree exist satisfying the functional equation (we have $a_0=1, a_1=0, a_2=n, n \ge 3$ for example and for low degree cases one can continue and get the next $a$'s - in degree $3$ already we have a quadratic for $a_3, a_3^2=-2$ and in degree $4$ various cases, however in all such I checked, the sum of the coefficients is far from $1$ so that condition is essential

Comment: One can let $a_3=-n+1-\sum_{j=4}^n a_k$ to force $f(1)=2$.

Comment: Furthermore $a_3=-a_{n-1}/a_n$.

Comment: Just checked there is no other solution with real coefficients for $\deg f \leq 17$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution that was found during an exam :
first let $Deg_p=n>2$ now let :
$$p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n{a_ix^i}$$
so we have  :
$$p(x)p(\frac{1}{x})=\sum_{i=0}^n{a_ix^i}\sum_{i=0}^n{a_ix^{-i}}=1+\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i(x+\frac{1}{x})^i}$$
first we will look at the constant therm on the both side which is :
$$1+a_0=\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i^2}$$
now we will look at the term $x^n$ at both sides. which gives :
$$a_na_0=a_n$$
since $a_n$ can not be $0$ we must have $a_0=1$ , we rewrite the first condition as :
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i^2}=1$$
now lets calculate the term $x^{n-1}$ on both side we have :
$$a_na_1+a_{n-1}=a_{n-1}$$
which gives $a_1=0$ now we look at the term $n-2$ :
$$a_na_2+a_{n-2}=na_n+a_{n-2}$$
so we have $a_2=n$ but this gives contradiction with the assumption that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i^2}=1 \ge a_2^2=n^2$$
so we have $n\le 2$ if $n=1$ then we clearly have
$p(1)=2,p(2)=3$ (from $x=1$) so we have $a_1+a_0=2,2a_1+a_0=3$ so $a_1=1,a_0=1$ and $p(x)=x+1$ which clearly works.
if $n=2$ remember we proved $a_1=0$ this also works for $n=2$ so we have
$$p(x)=ax^2+1$$
but since $p(1)=2$ we have $a=1$ bot the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+1$ doesn't work in the statement.
so we are done

Comment: I don't get it right: what do you mean by *constant term*?  That one containing no (trivial) power of $x$?  I agree, on the left hand side it's the sum of squares of the coefficients of $p$.  But on the right hand side some more terms will appear, namely in all $(x+1/x)^i$ where $i$ is even.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

*Concerning the constant term*

If the degree $n$ of $f$ is one, there's a unique solution satisfying the functional equation and $f(1)=2$.  For $n\in\{2,3\}$ several functions satisfy the functional equation but not $f(1)=2$.  From now on let $n\geq4$.

We already know that then $f$ has the form
$$f(x)=1+nx^2+\sum_{j=3}^n ajx^j.$$
The constant term of $f(x)f(1/x)$ is the sum of the squares of the coefficients of $f$.  The constant term of $f(x+1/x)$ arises when expanding $(x+1/x)^j$ for even $j$, that is
$$1+2n+\binom{4}{2}a_4+\binom{6}{3}a_6+\binom{8}{4}a_8+\cdots$$
Together with the functional equation we have
$$1^2+n^2+\sum_{j=3}^{n}a_j^{2}=1+2n+\binom{4}{2}a_4+\binom{6}{3}a_6+\binom{8}{4}a_8+\cdots+1.$$
You'll find functions satisfying this equation.  But the function must also satisfy $f(1)=2$, that is
$$1+n+\sum_{j=3}^{n}a_j=2\text{, that is }
\sum_{j=3}^{n}a_j=1-n.$$